# Tomcat 8 is not scanning apache tiles TLD file inside the jar

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8, apache-tiles, tiles-3

I'm setting up the spring webmvc project using spring boot 2.0.0 version. If i run the application inside the embedded tomcat, it runs fine. I tried deploying it in external standalone tomcat-8 server, it is working fine over there too.  But i if package the war and deploy it in the tomcat-8 server configured within eclipse, then it throws below exception.

> The absolute uri: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be
>   resolved in either web.xml

I included the dependency in the pom file as below.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I ensured that the tiles-jsp jar is present inside the WEB-INF/lib folder. But still its failing as it is not able to scan the jar for TLD. I tried changing the catalina.properties to include **tiles-jsp*.jar**. But it is still failing.

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: I think I'm facing the same problem. Did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Does your IDE automatically import dependencies?

Try cleaning your maven dependencies.
Maven clean.

Or try the more brutal command `dependency:purge-local-repository`.

By the way notice that there's a newer version of your dependency `3.0.8` of 2017. The one that you are trying to use, the `3.0.4`, is of 2014.

Comment: i'm able to run it inside the embedded tomcat server and standalone server outside the eclipse. Only problem is that running it in inside the configured tomcat-8 server within eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For me, war file when deployed works perfect. Had an issue where, when I run it under tomcat from inside IDE(Eclipse/STS), it threw error. Maven clean really helped, no other change needed. MAven clean-->build--> restart eclipse/sts tomcat. it works like a charm. Answer by desoss prompted me to perform maven clean. Thanks @desoss.